# Divisibility of an expression by 11

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

How to prove that $5^{5n+1}+4^{5n+2}+3^{5n}$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is divisible by $11$ using mathematical induction?

I have tried and got to this $$5 \cdot 25 \cdot 25 \cdot 5^{5k+1}+4\cdot 16 \cdot 16 \cdot 4^{5k+2}+3\cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 3^{5k}$$
and I even skipped the first step.

Thanks in advance.

(I am sorry if the tags are not relevant to this question)

Comment: mod $11$:  $5^{5n+1}+4^{5n+2}+3^{5n}\equiv 5+16+1=22\equiv0$, since $5^5\equiv4^5\equiv3^5\equiv1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$3125\cdot5^{5k+1}+1024\cdot4^{5k+2}+243\cdot3^{5k}$$

$$=243\left(5^{5k+1}+4^{5k+2}+3^{5k}\right)+2882\cdot5^{5k+1}+781\cdot4^{5k+2},$$

and $2882$ and $781$ are divisible by $11$.

Comment: This is the hit I needed. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(n)=5^{5n+1}+4^{5n+2}+3^{5n}$

$$f(m+1)-3^5\cdot f(m)=5^{5(m+1)+1}+4^{5(m+1)+2}-3^5(5^{5m+1}+4^{5m+2})$$

$$=5^{5m+1}(5^5-3^5)+4^{5m+2}(4^5-3^5)$$  which is divisible by $11$

as  $3^5=9(22+5)\equiv1\pmod{11}, 5^5=5^2\cdot5^3\equiv3\cdot4\equiv1\pmod{11}$

Similarly, $4^5\equiv1\pmod{11}$

$$\implies11|f(m)\iff11\mid f(m+1)$$

Comment: Did you need to say also $4^5\equiv1\pmod{11}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, Yes, in y understanding,  we need to show $$3^5\equiv4^5\equiv5^5\equiv1\pmod{11}$$ so that $$11$$ divides $$5^5-3^5, 4^5-3^5$$

Comment: Yes  but I didn't see where you said $4^5\equiv1\pmod{11}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, There was a typo, which is rectified now

Comment: Thanks to you too, but I can't understand most of it. I haven't learned that yet.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*
Let $f(n)=5^{5n+1}+4^{5n+2}+3^{5n}$. Then
$$
f(n+1)-f(n)
=(5^5-1) \cdot5^{5 n + 1} + (4^5-1) \cdot 4^{5 n + 2} + (3^5-1) \cdot 3^{5n}
= 11(284\cdot5^{5 n + 1}+ 93 \cdot 4^{5 n + 2} +22\cdot 3^{5n})
$$

The crucial point is that $5^5-1,4^5-1,3^5-1$ are all divisible by $11$.

Comment: Actually, this proves that $f(n)$ is divisible by $22$.